# Download artifacts from local Maven Repository

Tags: maven, download, repository

Hey im new to maven and i was wondering if anyone knew if i had a bunch of files in a directory, can i make that directory a local repo for maven. the projects in there are not maven projects but would i be able to somehow downlaod those files onto another location using maven?

this is how the folder is organized:

```
patch

--new folder

----versions (multiple folders which contain zip files)
```

is there a way to getting the version folders and copying that to a different directory with a maven command like

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy -Dartifact=org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.4.0.GA:jar:sources -DoutputDirectory=/home/-Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true
```

Comment: It just crossed my mind that I might be making assumptions about your intended goal without being sure. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want these jars copied to the new destination - in order to zip them up, in order to be used by a different project as build dependencies, or in order to do something entirely different?

Comment: well i dont actually have anything to do with jar files. I have a folder full of software which do not contain jar files but the actual installation files or zip files for them. can i put them as is into the local repo and when needed using maven command extract just one version from the folder into a different directory. right now i wanna see if it is possible thats why im saying different directory on my own computer and them maybe later on download them onto a different VM.

Comment: im using maven specifically for just holding files which i can then retrieve later on. the files dont have anything to actually do with maven. i dont think its possible but i wanted to confirm if there is a way around it

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to the correct solution - same plugin, different mojo:

```
$ mvn maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=/path/to/output
```

This will dump all dependencies into the location of your choosing.

The `-DstripVersion=true` argument is useful if you want to have the jars by their canonical name without the version suffix (ie `log4j.jar` vs. `log4j-1.2.17.jar`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: would i have to "install" the dependency to the local repository as one will have to do with the artifacts?

Comment: No need to install. Next time you build from maven it will automatically pull jar from remote repo into local repo.